# The rain/snow/storm "let up"

Tags: meaning, idioms, ambiguity, dialects

What does "let up" denote in "the rain/storm has let up so we can go out/drive back home"?

With a context lacking clarity, should it be understood as, "the [hard] rain/storm has lessened up to a light sprinkle/gentle rain (making it safe to go out, drive, use the Internet again, etc.)," or "the rain/storm has stopped and the weather is now calm"?

> let up
>
> : to diminish, as in *I hope this rain lets up a little soon*. *When the snow lets up so I can see, I will drive to the store*. [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+up)
>
> : to cease, stop entirely, as in *The rain has let up so we can go out*. [Late 1700s] [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+up)

Comment: ***let up (n.)***: 
"cessation," 1837, from verbal phrase let up "cease, stop" (1787). In Old English the phrase meant "to put ashore." http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Let+up

Comment: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/let-up) shows that both readings are available:
› If ​bad ​weather or an ​unpleasant ​situation ​lets up, it ​stops or ​improves. >> (Macmillan agrees.) If there is insufficient context, the expression is thus ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've heard it used both ways. Further context will clarify which usage exists.

Basically, the speaker is saying, "It was raining too hard to drive home, but now I think it's safe enough." That can mean that it has stopped entirely or simply that it has lessened enough.

Comment: Sadly, I've heard a lot of usages I couldn't recommend. tchrist spells out ELU policy on answers: 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.'